# log base 2 equals log base 3 when analyzing time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Most solutions to Exercise 4.4.6 of Intro. to Algorithms 3rd edition say, 
n*log3(n) = Big omega of (n*lg(n)).

Dose it mean log3(n) is equivalent to log2(n) when we are discussing time complexity of algorithms?

Thanks

Comment: This may not give you a lot of points in your CS exams, but my crude estimate is that anything logarithmic with a base greater than one is pretty good.

Comment: Yes, because `log3(n) == log2(n)/log2(3)`.

Comment: Note that "log2(3)" in Oli Charlesworth's comment is a *constant* -- so it doesn't count in asymptotic complexity analysis, the same way O(42n) is just O(n).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as big-Oh notation is concerned, the base of the logarithms doesn't make any real difference, because of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) important property, called `Change of Base`.

According to this property, changing the base of the logarithm, in terms of big-oh notation, only affects the complexity by a constant factor.

So, yes. In terms of big-Oh notation, log3(n) is equivalent to log2(n).

Comment: how about log1.5(n)?. I am trying to solve recurrence of heapify function and I come to the conclusion on log3/2(n). I am not sure it's N or log(n)